# Error Renaming Files and folders codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, I had to rename some files and folders from my project, I used NotePad++ and minunciosamente changed names, it did 3 times, but always appears to me this message:

> Unable to load the requested file: header.php

Where could be the problem?

If anyone can help me I'm grateful.

Comment: share the code where you are loading header.php

Comment: This is the problem, I have no log of the error indicating where is the problem, just rename some files, I did both in code and in folders, do not have the file reference.

Comment: did u changed the name of this file `header.php`

Comment: hi DevPro

I not changed the header.php.

What I did was change the name of my theme was before: theme-yellow.
I searched all theme-yellow references and renamed for theme-blue.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: can you mention the file names and code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller method and see what file is being called

It could be Header.php 
 CI is case sensitive

if you file is in a folder in the viewfolder

Then load       folder/file

It could be that the methods file name changed

But the file name is still the same or vice versa.

Comment: Hello, I just do not understand why this error.

Explaining in NotePed ++ I did a search for the entire project, respecting uppercase and lowercase

also correctly rename folders.

throughout the project I did rename correctly, did the procedure several times always with attention, but do not get to the root of the problem.

anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Just an advise use sublime text 3 is better. And you' install plugins which will make your CI experience better..

Answer (score 0):

This seems in your template or anywhere you load the `$this->load->view('header.php');` but the file name has been changed to another name. So make sure you are trying to load the file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

theres a file called .htaccess

inside it on line 3

```
RewriteBase /your new folder name/
```

change to the new folder name